# Getting a specific option relative to selected one (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have a `select` area with a bunch of `options`, one of which has `selected` in action (this stuff is all generated with PHP, if curious). Each of them has a value which is added to a web address and is redirected to on click. In essence, this;

```html
<select id="mylist" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="lorem">        Option 5 </option>
    <option value="ipsum">        Option 4 </option>
    <option value="dolor">        Option 3 </option> //want this value
    <option value="sit" selected> Option 2 </option>
    <option value="amet,">        Option 1 </option>
</select>
```

Is there any way to get the value of the option directly ABOVE the selected one using JavaScript/jQuery or the likes? Is there also a way to trigger something if the selected option is on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain JavaScript, particularly [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling). Note that changing the select element’s value won’t change its `selected` attribute set on your preprocessor’s output. This code will get the previous option element’s value, unless the selected one is the first:

```js
document.getElementById('mylist').addEventListener('change',function(){
    var selectedOption = this.querySelector('[selected]');
    var precedingSelected = selectedOption.previousElementSibling;
    var value = precedingSelected == null ?
                selectedOption.value :
                precedingSelected.value;
    alert(value); // dolor
});
```

```html
    <select id="mylist">
       <option value="lorem">        Option 5 </option>
       <option value="ipsum">        Option 4 </option>
       <option value="dolor">        Option 3 </option>
       <option value="sit" selected> Option 2 </option>
       <option value="amet,">        Option 1 </option>
    </select>
```

If you adapt something like this, make sure to attributively select the option the user chose.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using inline script. You can use [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev) method to get previous value like this:

```
$('#mylist').on('change',function(){
   var prevValue = $(this).find('option:selected').prev().val();
   window.location.href=prevValue; // not sure about your href
});
```

Well as commented by Rayon, if you selected the first option then you might want to get last value. Then you can do like this:

```
$('#mylist').on('change',function(){
   var optionSelected = $(this).find('option:selected');
   var desiredValue = optionSelected.prev().length 
        ? 
      optionSelected.prev().val() : $(this).find('option:last').val();
   window.location.href=desiredValue; // not sure about your href
});
```

Comment: What if the first option is selected ?